# Reuse text on a bash command

Tags: bash, cp

If i'm writing a long command or just typing an extensive file path, is there any that i can "reuse" it with some command shortcut?

e.g:

1.`cp /home/myuser/really/big/file/here/and/there.png /home/myuser/really/big/file/here/and/there.png.bkp`

Do i really have to type it all over again?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)

```
cp /home/myuser/really/big/file/here/and/there.png{,.bkp}
```

Comment: +1 and you can go even shorter: `cp /home/myuser/really/big/file/here/and/there.{,.bkp}`

Comment: @peth: Oops, yes, you're correct. So we can actually go even shorter: `cp /home/myuser/really/big/file/here/and/there{,.bkp}` :)

Answer (score 4):

Also, [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) can work here:

```
cp /home/myuser/really/big/file/here/and/there.png !#:1.bkp
```

where the `!#:1` part refers to the first argument of the command you're currently typing.

Answer (score 1):

You can save lots of time typing that by using tab expansion, the tilde shortcut, and command history.

For instance,

```
~/r[tab]/b[tab]/f[tab]/h[tab]/a[tab]/t[tab]/
```

(where [tab] means "press the Tab key") would expand to

```
/home/myuser/really/big/file/here/and/there
```

You could also type

```
cp /home/myuser/really/big/file/here/and/there.png /some/destination
```

then press up-arrow and just change the last three letters of the filename