# In bash, how can I rename a file without repeating the path?

Tags: bash, rename, mv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reuse text on a bash command](https://superuser.com/questions/294685/reuse-text-on-a-bash-command)

If I want to rename a file a few directories deep, how can I avoid repeating the path?

For example:

```
mv path/to/old_filename.txt path/to/new_filename.txt
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to make this:

```
mv path/to/old_filename.txt (?)new_filename.txt
```

Where `(?)` would be some way of saying "in the same directory."

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using bash [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators):

```
mv path/to/oldfile !#:1:h/newfile
```

where `!#:1:h` means: from the line you're currently typing ("!#"), take the first word (":1"), then take only the path component (":h" -- the head) from it.

Comment: This is the closest to what the original questioner assumed the solution might be, and is useful to know, so +1.

Comment: Cool! I think Darth's brace expansion method is easier, but this is exactly what I asked for.

Comment: I've learned two great new things today. Also, I will forever think of brace expansion as "Darth's brace expansion" because it sounds awesome.

Answer (score 65):

You can use brace expansion:
`mv path/to/{old_filename.txt,new_filename.txt}`

[Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) is a link to the GNU guide on brace expansion in the bash shell, which defines a list of substitutes and tells bash to repeat the parameter using a different substitute each time it repeats.

For example,

```
a{b,c,dd,e}
```

will be expanded to

```
ab ac add ae
```

The only caveat is that the expanded repetitions must be able to follow each other as arguments to the target program.

Comment: Or keeping it to a minimum: `mv path/to/{old,new}_filename.txt`. This also helps reversal or other kinds of close-to-repetition of the command. I have many times done e.g. `mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf{,.backup}`, being able to reverse the process by the simple change `mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf{.backup,}`.

Answer (score 28):

[Darth's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/298081/in-bash-how-can-i-rename-a-file-without-repeating-the-path/298085#298085) above is clever, but if you want to use an approach with `cd`, you could also consider using a subshell:

```
(cd path/to && mv old_filename.txt new_filename.txt)
```

Because the directory change takes place in the subshell, you will not actually change directories in your interactive shell.

Comment: Significant drawback: You cannot use tab-completion for `old_filename.txt`.

Answer (score 11):

Another alternative that is useful, if you are going to do several commands in the directory, is this:

```
pushd /path/to
mv oldfile newfile
...
popd
```