# Unix utility to rename file(s) in an editor or inline

Tags: unix, shell, rename

I am looking for a unix command-line program for renaming file (or files) visually, in an editor or inline (in the same manner as you rename a file on your desktop).

**Example.** I often need to rename a file somewhere deep. Imagine a file with a wrong `.js.txt` extension (`_` is a cursor):

```
$ mv deep/inside/there/is/a/file.js.txt _
```

It is confusing to repeat the whole path as second argument to `mv`:

```
$ mv deep/inside/there/is/a/file.js.txt deep/inside/there/is/a/file.js
```

(I know I can use the mouse, but it is still error-prone). I'd better press `Home` and change `mv` to a visual renamer (imagine it's called `vmv`). E.g.:

```
$ vmv somewhere/deep/inside/there/is/a/file.js.txt
EDIT FILE NAME: somewhere/deep/inside/there/is/a/file.js.txt_
```

Comment: I don't know what remane files in an editor means.. do you mean while open?  I don't know if it's possible to rename a file while open in an editor.  If you mean writing the copy commands in an editor, how about writing a script, you write your mv lines in there , copy/paste for any repetition of a long directory, and execute it?

Comment: `mv deep/inside/there/is/a/file.js{.txt,}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reuse text on a bash command](http://superuser.com/questions/294685/reuse-text-on-a-bash-command)

Comment: Also [in-bash-how-can-i-rename-a-file-without-repeating-the-path](http://superuser.com/questions/298081/in-bash-how-can-i-rename-a-file-without-repeating-the-path)

Comment: @Nifle, thanks for pointers! I wasn't looking for bash-specific solution. I use [fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell) as my shell. That's why I didn't mention bash in the question.

Comment: @barlop, I was thinking about `vidir` command, but didn't know its name ;-) Thanks @grawity for a great answer below!

Comment: @Ignacio, thank you! Your solution is bash-specific, but luckily [fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell) (shell of my choice) supports brace expansions too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your own. Put this in a file called `vmv`, make it executable, put it in `~/bin` or wherever you'd like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for oldname; do
    read -rep "Edit: " -i "$oldname" newname
    if [[ $oldname != $newname ]]; then
        mv -v "$oldname" "$newname" || exit $?
    fi
fi
```

Does exactly what you want.

---

In bash, you can edit the current command line in an editor:

> `mv deep/inside/there/is/a/file.js.txt` <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd>

*moreutils* has:

```
vidir
```

Debian comes with a Perl script that accepts regexps:

```
prename 's/\.txt$//' file.js.txt
```

Comment: +1 for two extra solutions I never even knew about (bash and vidir)